# glcolorconvert 1.14.4 has large memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, gstreamer, buildroot

I am using gstreamer 1.14.4 in buildroot on a rockchip rk3288. I have noticed, when I attempt to use glcolorconvert in a pipeline it leaks. ALOT. This is a simplified example using xray.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v \
v4l2src device=/dev/video5 ! \
image/jpeg,width=1280,height=720 ! \
videorate ! \
image/jpeg,framerate=15/1 ! \
queue leaky=2 name=vidQ ! \
jpegdec ! \
video/x-raw,format=I420 ! \
glupload ! \
glcolorconvert ! \
gleffects_xray ! \
glcolorconvert ! \
gldownload ! \
kmssink &
```

In 15 minutes this leaked 90 MB !

If I use software videoconvert I do not get the memory leak, but videoconvert can be very slow, which slows down the framerate

```
v4l2src device=/dev/video5 ! \
image/jpeg,width=1280,height=720 ! \
videorate ! \
image/jpeg,framerate=15/1 ! \
queue leaky=2 name=vidQ ! \
jpegdec ! \
video/x-raw,format=I420 ! \
videoconvert ! \
glupload ! \
gleffects_xray ! \
gldownload ! \
videoconvert ! \
kmssink &
```

The performance of the glcolorconvert is very good, especially for my application, but I cannot afford memory leaks like this. I am not sure where to look for appropriate patches, but I have not yet found a patch or thread that addresses this fix .

Comment: if you implement [this](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=757974) patch, does it fix the issue?

Comment: no it does not. Those patches are older, and while they dont apply directly, the code changed in the patches has already been applied to my glcolorconvert